# Drop to QTDesigner using PyQt4

Tags: python, pyqt, qt-designer

Using PyQt4 + QT4.8.4, I'd like to drop (external) textual content to a widget defined as a PyQt4 plugin in QtDesigner

I use two python classes :

- widgetlabelplugin.py inherited from QPyDesignerCustomWidgetPlugin
- widgetlabel.py inherited from QLabel

Overriding the dropEvent in (widgetlabel.py), I'm able to retrieve "external textual content" and to set _model property.

I do the following steps :

1. Launch designer by previously setting PYQTDESIGNERPATH to the
   .py path
2. Create a dialog without button
3. Drop a PyGMT/ WiddgetLabel on the dialog
4. Drop a "textual content" (from notepad) to the widgetlabel label

   -> at this step, the label is updated on the dialog but not on the properties browser on the right
5. Save Dialog from Qt designer tool bar

   -> ui file doesn't contain any "textual content" neither for QLabel/text, nor WidgetLabel/model
6. In Qt designer, If I select dialog background and reselect WidgetLabel, properties are updated in the browser, they are still not saved if I save the ui !

python class : widgetlabelplugin.py

```
# A demonstration custom widget plugin for PROJECT Qt Designer.
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtDesigner

from widgetlabel import WidgetLabel

# This class implements the interface expected by Qt Designer to access the
# custom widget.  See the description of the QDesignerCustomWidgetInterface
# class for full details.
class WidgetLabelPlugin(QtDesigner.QPyDesignerCustomWidgetPlugin):

    # Initialise the instance.
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(WidgetLabelPlugin, self).__init__(parent)

        self._initialized = False

    # Initialise the custom widget for use with the specified formEditor
    # interface.
    def initialize(self, formEditor):
        if self._initialized:
            return

        self._initialized = True

    # Return True if the custom widget has been intialised.
    def isInitialized(self):
        return self._initialized

    # Return a new instance of the custom widget with the given parent.
    def createWidget(self, parent):
        return WidgetLabel(parent)

    # Return the name of the class that implements the custom widget.
    def name(self):
        return "WidgetLabel"

    # Return the name of the group to which the custom widget belongs.  A new
    # group will be created if it doesn't already exist.
    def group(self):
        return "PyGMT"

    # Return the icon used to represent the custom widget in Designer's widget
    # box.
    def icon(self):
        return QtGui.QIcon(":/designer/frame.png")

    # Return a short description of the custom widget used by Designer in a
    # tool tip.
    def toolTip(self):
        return "Satis demonstration widget"

    # Return a full description of the custom widget used by Designer in
    # "What's This?" help for the widget.
    def whatsThis(self):
        return "WidgetLabel is a demonstration custom widget written in Python " \
               "using PyQt."

    # Return True if the custom widget acts as a container for other widgets.
    def isContainer(self):
        return False

    # Return the name of the module containing the class that implements the
    # custom widget.  It may include a module path.
    def includeFile(self):
        return "WidgetLabel"
```

python class : widgetlabel.py

```
#############################################################################
##
## This file is part of the examples of PROJECT Qt Designer.
##
#############################################################################

from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

# This is the class that implements the custom widget for PROJECT.
class WidgetLabel(QtGui.QLabel):

    #model changed signal
    modelChanged = QtCore.pyqtSignal(QtCore.QString)

    # Initialise the instance.
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(WidgetLabel, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.setText("Label")

        # Initialise the model property. 
        self._model = None

###########################################################################
                              # DRAG & DROP PART #

###########################################################################
    def dragEnterEvent(self, e):
         if e.mimeData().hasFormat("text/plain"):
             e.setDropAction(QtCore.Qt.CopyAction)
             e.accept()
         else:
             e.ignore()

    def dragMoveEvent(self, event):
         if event.mimeData().hasFormat("text/plain"):
             event.setDropAction(QtCore.Qt.CopyAction)
             event.accept()
         else:
             event.ignore

    def dropEvent(self, e):
         e.acceptProposedAction()
         bStream = e.mimeData().retrieveData("text/plain",
                                             QtCore.QVariant.ByteArray)

         self.setModel(QtCore.QString(str(bStream.toByteArray())))

    # The getter for the zoom property.
    def getModel(self):
        return self._model

    # The setter for the model property.  We also make define this as a Qt slot
    # which can be connected to Qt signals in Qt Designer.
    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(QtCore.QString)
    def setModel(self, model):
#        print "new model", model
        # Set QLabel text
        self.setText(model)

        # Don't do anything if nothing has changed.
        if self._model == model:
            return

        # Remember the new model level.
        self._model = model

        # Emit the Qt signal to say that the model level has changed.
        self.modelChanged.emit(model)

    # The resetter for the model property.
    def resetModel(self):
        self.setModel(None)

    # Define the model property.  Changing the value of this in Qt Designer's
    # property editor causes the model to change dynamically.
    model = QtCore.pyqtProperty(QtCore.QString, getModel, setModel, resetModel)

# Display the custom widget if the script is being run directly from the
# command line.
if __name__ == "__main__":

    import sys

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

    demo = WidgetLabel()
    demo.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```